# Html Table of radio buttons. Make Radio button clickable anywhere in cell

Tags: html, css, html-table, alignment, radiobuttonlist

I want to make the radio buttons take up the full cell they are in- without affecting the table or cell size. (making it easier to click)
I do not need them to have any string value, simply the button placement & style is what I am after.
I have been testing with css that will make it square but it always makes the radio button overlap the cell or makes the table change shape.
How can I customize these radio buttons?

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated. I am fairly new to this and have gotten in over my head.

```css
.st {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 2px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.st-header_corner {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0px 2px;
  background: none;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1c1b1b;
  border-right: 1px solid #1c1b1b;
}
.st-header_row {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0px 2px;
  background: lighten(#ddd, 10%);
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-right: 1px solid #1c1b1b;
}
.st-header_col {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0px 2px;
  background: lighten(#ddd, 10%);
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1c1b1b;
}
.st-cell_basic {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background: #ffffff;
}
.st-cell_plus {
  border: 1px solid darken(#ddd, 10%);
  background: #ddd;
}

.st-Radio:not([disabled]){
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 1;
}
.st-Radio:not([disabled]):hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px green;
  outline: 4px solid green;
}

.st-Radio:not([disabled]):checked+span {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: green;
  padding: 0px; 
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;  
}
```

```html
<table class="st">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="st-header_corner">&nbsp;/&nbsp;</th>
      <th class="st-header_col">30</th>
      <th class="st-header_col">31</th>
      <th class="st-header_col">32</th>
      <th class="st-header_col">33</th>
      <th class="st-header_col">34</th>
      <th class="st-header_col">35</th>
      <th class="st-header_col">36</th>
      <th class="st-header_col">38</th>
      <th class="st-header_col">40</th>
      <th class="st-header_col">42</th>
      <th class="st-header_col">44</th>
      <th class="st-header_col">46</th>
      <th class="st-header_col">48</th>
      <th class="st-header_col">50</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="st-header_row">30</td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3030" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3030" data-option-position="2"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3130" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3130" data-option-position="2"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3230" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3230" data-option-position="2"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3330" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3330" data-option-position="2"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3430" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3430" data-option-position="2"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3530" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3530" data-option-position="2"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3630" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3630" data-option-position="2"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3830" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3830" data-option-position="2"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="4030" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="4030" data-option-position="2"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="4230" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="4230" data-option-position="2"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="4430" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="4430" data-option-position="2"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_plus"><label><input id="4630" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="4630" data-option-position="2"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_plus"><label><input id="4830" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="4830" data-option-position="2"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_plus"><label><input id="5030" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="5030" data-option-position="2"><span></span></label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="st-header_row">32</td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3032" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3032" data-option-position="2"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3132" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3132" data-option-position="2"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3232" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3232" data-option-position="2"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3332" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3332" data-option-position="2"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3432" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3432" data-option-position="2"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3532" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3532" data-option-position="2"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3632" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3632" data-option-position="2"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3832" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3832" data-option-position="2"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="4032" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="4032" data-option-position="2"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="4232" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="4232" data-option-position="2"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="4432" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="4432" data-option-position="2"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_plus"><label><input id="4632" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="4632" data-option-position="2"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_plus"><label><input id="4832" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="4832" data-option-position="2"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_plus"><label><input id="5032" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="5032" data-option-position="2"><span></span></label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="st-header_row">34</td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3034" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3034" data-option-position="2"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3134" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3134" data-option-position="2"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3234" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3234" data-option-position="2"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3334" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3334" data-option-position="2"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3434" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3434" data-option-position="2"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3534" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3534" data-option-position="2"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3634" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3634" data-option-position="2"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3834" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3834" data-option-position="2"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="4034" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="4034" data-option-position="2"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="4234" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="4234" data-option-position="2"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="4434" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="4434" data-option-position="2"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_plus"><label><input id="4634" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="4634" disabled data-option-position="2"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_plus"><label><input id="4834" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="4834" disabled data-option-position="2"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_plus"><label><input id="5034" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="5034" disabled data-option-position="2"><span></span></label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="st-header_row">36</td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3036" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3036" disabled data-option-position="2"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3136" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3136" disabled data-option-position="2"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3236" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3236" data-option-position="2"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3336" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3336" data-option-position="2"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3436" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3436" data-option-position="2"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3536" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3536" disabled data-option-position="2"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3636" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3636" data-option-position="2"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3836" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3836" data-option-position="2"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="4036" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="4036" data-option-position="2"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="4236" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="4236" disabled data-option-position="2"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="4436" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="4436" disabled data-option-position="2"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_plus"><label><input id="4636" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="4636" disabled data-option-position="2"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_plus"><label><input id="4836" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="4836" disabled data-option-position="2"><span></span></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_plus"><label><input id="5036" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="5036" disabled data-option-position="2"><span></span></label></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I can't understand what is the problem or what do you want to achieve. What do you mean with 'make the radio buttons style line up with the table they are set in'?

Comment: I think I see it. The green squares aren't centered in the bordered grid boxes. it would help if the example was simplified and enlarged.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Apologies, I updated my wording. The radio buttons (shaped like squares inside the table cells), can I line the edges up perfectly or near perfect with the cell? The div cell itself doesn't seem to want to remain a perfect square. (edit: i guess its not really a cell, but I was using a "html table" and switched to div layout, it seemed to cooperate better.)

Comment: UPDATE: New code and better description.

Comment: Wrap each of the radios in a `label` element and use CSS to make those `label`s take up 100% of the table cell (or whatever).

Comment: like this? : 
`<td class="st-cell_basic">` `<label>` `<input id="3036" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3036" disabled data-option-position="2">` `</label>` `</td>`

Comment: That did work! Leading me to my style issue. Ive updated the code to show the radios wrapped in a label. I added a span after the radio inputs to create the block i want to be able to customize, but it throws everything off.

Comment: UPDATED CODE: Now when I click one and it applies a style, it wont lay it over the radio button and resizes the cell/table.

Answer (score 0):

Modified code to style the radio buttons. A lot of this had to do with the :before elements. I would still like to know how to bring each of these radio *boxes* to the edge of its cell.

```css
.st {
  border-collapse: seperate;
  border-spacing: 0.0625em;
  padding: 0 auto;
  user-select: none;
}

.st-headerC {
  background: none;
}
.st-headerH,
.st-headerV {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: white;
  background: black;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black, 1px 1px 2px white;
  padding: 0.125em 0.125em;
  width: 1.25em;
  height: 1.25em;
}
.st-cell_basic {
   border: 1px solid black;
  background: white;
  margin: 0;
}
.st-cell_plus {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: lightgray;
  margin: 0;
}
input[type="radio"].st-Radio {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 1.25em;
  height: 1.25em;
  border: 1px solid darkgray;
  border-radius: 0%;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0px gray inset;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type="radio"].st-Radio:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0px orange inset;
}
input[type="radio"].st-Radio:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 20% auto;
  border-radius: 0%;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

input[type="radio"].st-Radio:checked:before {
  background: lightgreen;
  box-shadow: lime 0px 0px 3px 1px;
}
```

```html
<table class="st">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="st-headerC">&nbsp;</th>
      <th class="st-headerH">30</th>
      <th class="st-headerH">31</th>
      <th class="st-headerH">32</th>
      <th class="st-headerH">33</th>
      <th class="st-headerH">34</th>
      <th class="st-headerH">35</th>
      <th class="st-headerH">36</th>
      <th class="st-headerH">38</th>
      <th class="st-headerH">40</th>
      <th class="st-headerH">42</th>
      <th class="st-headerH">44</th>
      <th class="st-headerH">46</th>
      <th class="st-headerH">48</th>
      <th class="st-headerH">50</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class="st-headerV">30</th>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3030" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3030" data-option-position="2"><label for="3030"><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3130" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3130" data-option-position="2"><label for="3130"><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3230" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3230" data-option-position="2"><label for="3230"><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3330" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3330" data-option-position="2"><label for="3330"><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3430" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3430" data-option-position="2"><label for="3430"><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3530" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3530" data-option-position="2"><label for="3530"><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3630" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3630" data-option-position="2"><label for="3630"><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3830" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3830" data-option-position="2"><label for="3830"><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="4030" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="4030" data-option-position="2"><label for="4030"><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="4230" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="4230" data-option-position="2"><label for="4230"><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="4430" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="4430" data-option-position="2"><label for="4430"><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_plus"><label><input id="4630" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="4630" data-option-position="2"><label for="4630"><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_plus"><label><input id="4830" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="4830" data-option-position="2"><label for="4830"><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_plus"><label><input id="5030" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="5030" data-option-position="2"><label for="5030"><span></span></label></label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="st-headerV">32</th>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3032" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3032" data-option-position="2"><label for="3032"><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3132" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3132" data-option-position="2"><label for="3132"><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3232" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3232" data-option-position="2"><label for="3232"><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3332" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3332" data-option-position="2"><label for="3332"><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3432" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3432" data-option-position="2"><label for="3432"><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3532" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3532" data-option-position="2"><label for="3532"><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3632" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3632" data-option-position="2"><label for="3632"><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3832" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3832" data-option-position="2"><label for="3832"><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="4032" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="4032" data-option-position="2"><label for="4032"><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="4232" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="4232" data-option-position="2"><label for="4232"><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="4432" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="4432" data-option-position="2"><label for="4432"><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_plus"><label><input id="4632" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="4632" data-option-position="2"><label for="4632"><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_plus"><label><input id="4832" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="4832" data-option-position="2"><label for="4832"><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_plus"><label><input id="5032" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="5032" data-option-position="2"><label for="5032"><span></span></label></label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="st-headerV">34</th>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3034" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3034" data-option-position="2"><label for="3034"><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3134" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3134" data-option-position="2"><label for="3134"><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3234" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3234" data-option-position="2"><label for="3234"><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3334" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3334" data-option-position="2"><label for="3334"><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3434" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3434" data-option-position="2"><label for="3434"><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3534" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3534" data-option-position="2"><label for="3534"><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3634" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3634" data-option-position="2"><label for="3634"><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3834" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3834" data-option-position="2"><label for="3834"><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="4034" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="4034" data-option-position="2"><label for="4034"><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="4234" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="4234" data-option-position="2"><label for="4234"><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="4434" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="4434" data-option-position="2"><label for="4434"><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_plus"><label><label><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_plus"><label><label><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_plus"><label><label><span></span></label></label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="st-headerV">36</th>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><label><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><label><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3236" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3236" data-option-position="2"><label for="3236"><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3336" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3336" data-option-position="2"><label for="3336"><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3436" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3436" data-option-position="2"><label for="3436"><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><label><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3636" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3636" data-option-position="2"><label for="3636"><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="3836" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="3836" data-option-position="2"><label for="3836"><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><input id="4036" class="st-Radio" type="radio" name="size" value="4036" data-option-position="2"><label for="4036"><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><label><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_basic"><label><label><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_plus"><label><label><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_plus"><label><label><span></span></label></label></td>
      <td class="st-cell_plus"><label><label><span></span></label></label></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```